# How to use replace function in ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have this below json from this below code

```
"SMTPMessage":"%%=v(Field(@row,"SMTPMessage"))=%%"

"SMTPMessage":"{"Source":"MITS_LOG", "Machine":"ATL1S07WSLOT042"}"
```

Now i want to make it as a single string like below

```
"SMTPMessage":"Source:MITS_LOG-Machine-ATL1S07WSLOT042"
```

How can we do it in ampscript.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I would use Guide Template Language to parse your JSON object in conjunction with AMPscript. So your code would look like this:

```
%%[
var @SMTPMessage
set @SMTPMessage = Field(@row,"SMTPMessage")
]%%

  {{.datasource SMTPMessage type=variable}}
  {{.data}}
  { "target" : "@SMTPMessage" }
  {{/data}}

<p>"SMTPMessage":"Source:{{Source}}-Machine-{{Machine}}"</p>

  {{/datasource}}
```

Note that if you are using this on a CloudPage, you need to reset delimiters in OMM by adding this line after your AMPscript block:

```
%%{={{ }}=}%%
```